# Windows 2008 r2 RDP issues

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-7, rdp

I have machines on another network, I am finding some strange behavior. I can RDP onto some machines, other machines I receive this error.

Logon: "You must be granted the Allow log on through the Terminal (or Remote Desktop) Services Right"

I am able to remote onto my DC but not on my App server, I have looked at the group policy but wouldn't that be the roles for all machines on the network?

I am on a Windows 7 box, what I am trying to get too is Windows 2008 R2 on another network but the same network the DC is on I am in both remote desktop groups.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be added to the Remote Desktops Users or Administrator group under Local Users and Groups on the machine you're trying to access in order to use RDP.

Answer (score 0):

This error message appears when user you trying to connect with, does not have permissions to connect with Remote Desktop. To fix this, you'll have to add that user in either Remote Desktop Users or Administrators group. Note that you'll have to connect to remote server at least once to perform these steps with some sort of console login. Here are the steps.

1. Go to **Server Manager** of remote computer.
2. Under Server Manager, Go to **Local users and Groups** and then **users**.
3. Select the user you are trying to connect with and right click on it.
4. Click on **Properties**.
5. Click on **Member of** tab.
6. Click on **Add** button then **Advanced** button.
7. Click on **Find Now** button.
8. Select **Remote Desktop Users** group and then click **OK**.
9. Click **OK** twice. Now try to connect again.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I am in the list you mentioned. When I clicked ok, said I was already a member of that group.

Comment: If user is already member of Remote Desktop User, then you should try this ..
Under Run menu, type 'secpol.msc' and click Ok.
    The Local Security Policy window should open up.
    Expand the 'Local Policies' node and click 'User Rights Assignment'.
    On the right hand side, double click on 'Allow log on through Terminal Services' or 'Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services'.
    Click 'Add User or Group' and enter 'Remote Desktop Users'.
    Click Ok and Ok again to dismiss both dialog boxes.
    Reboot your system and try to reconnect.